# Mandelbrot in Java using 4 threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Would anyone be able to tell me what is wrong with this code where I have attempted to implement 4 threads into a Mandelbrot program. The first half of the image in the file is not rendering. Thanks!

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package Week2;

/**
*
 * @author Alex Humphris
 */
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.io.File;

public class ParallelMandelbrot4 extends Thread {

final static int N = 4096;
final static int CUTOFF = 100;

static int[][] set = new int[N][N];

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Calculate set
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ParallelMandelbrot4 thread0 = new ParallelMandelbrot4(0);
    ParallelMandelbrot4 thread1 = new ParallelMandelbrot4(1);
    ParallelMandelbrot4 thread2 = new ParallelMandelbrot4(2);
    ParallelMandelbrot4 thread3 = new ParallelMandelbrot4(3);

    thread0.start();
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();

    thread0.join();
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Calculation completed in "
            + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");

    // Plot image
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(N, N,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Draw pixels
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {

            int k = set[i][j];

            float level;
            if (k < CUTOFF) {
                level = (float) k / CUTOFF;
            } else {
                level = 0;
            }
            Color c = new Color(0, level, 0);  // Green
            img.setRGB(i, j, c.getRGB());
        }
    }

    // Print file
    ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", new File("Mandelbrot.png"));
}

int me;

public ParallelMandelbrot4(int me) {
    this.me = me;
}

public void run() {

    int begin, end;

    if (me == 0) {
        begin = 0;
        end = (N / 4) * 1;
    }
    if (me == 1) {
        begin = (N / 4) * 1;
        end = (N / 4) * 2;
    }
    if (me == 2) {
        begin = (N / 4) * 2;
        end = (N / 4) * 3;
    } else {  // me == 1
        begin = (N / 4) * 3;
        end = N;
    }

    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {

            double cr = (4.0 * i - 2 * N) / N;
            double ci = (4.0 * j - 2 * N) / N;

            double zr = cr, zi = ci;

            int k = 0;
            while (k < CUTOFF && zr * zr + zi * zi < 4.0) {

                // z = c + z * z
                double newr = cr + zr * zr - zi * zi;
                double newi = ci + 2 * zr * zi;

                zr = newr;
                zi = newi;

                k++;
            }

            set[i][j] = k;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There error lies in your run() statement. By adding the if statement for `(me == 3)`, the entire image is rendered, whereas before, the `else` statement at the end was being called in 3 different threads.

This is because of the else at the end of your code. Say for example `me` is 1. When it is one, it will execute the code in the `if (me == 1)` statement, and it will also execute the code at the end, as `me` is not equal to 2.

To fix this, I would recommend using the `if else` statements:

```
int begin = 0, end = 0;

    if (me == 0) {
        begin = 0;
        end = (N / 4) * 1;
    }
    else if (me == 1) {
        begin = (N / 4) * 1;
        end = (N / 4) * 2;
    }
    else if (me == 2) {
        begin = (N / 4) * 2;
        end = (N / 4) * 3;
    } 
    else if (me == 3) { 
        begin = (N / 4) * 3;
        end = N;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ! I knew it would be something stupid seeing as I am learning new concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The multithreading part is almost correct. It's the constructor that had some issues. You should consider making `me` a final private variable. @Skepter's answer is correct. This is how it looks in my IDE and that gave me an idea with the funkiness of the `if-else` you are using.[image]

Fixing it thus should work:

```
private final int me;

public ParallelMandelbrot4(int me) {
    this.me = me;
}

public void run() {

    int begin, end;

    if (me == 0) {
        begin = 0;
        end = (N / 4) * 1;
    }
    else if (me == 1) {
        begin = (N / 4) * 1;
        end = (N / 4) * 2;
    }
    else if (me == 2) {
        begin = (N / 4) * 2;
        end = (N / 4) * 3;
    } else {  // me == 3
        begin = (N / 4) * 3;
        end = N;
    }
```